# extjs and struts integration

Tags: java, json, extjs, struts2

i'm trying to use struts2-json-plugin to integrate struts actions and extjs.
i want to send json from extjs to struts2 action. this json contains all fields of my bean (UserEntity). but the setter of the action class does not call.
here is my code:

UserAction.java

```
public class UserAction extends BaseAction {

      private UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

      public UserEntity getUserEntity() {
           return userEntity;
      }

      public void setUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
           this.userEntity = userEntity;
      }

      ...
}
```

struts.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">

        <action name="saveOrUpdateUserAction" class="ir.emad.action.UserAction" method="saveOrUpdateUser">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">userEntity</param>
            </result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

and my UserStore.js

```
    Ext.define('AM.store.UserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.UserModel',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'listAllUsersAction',
            update: 'saveOrUpdateUserAction'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'userEntity',
            successProperty: 'success',
            encode: true
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'

    }
});
```

my problem is the setter of userEntity never called.if i change the setter to below code every thing is fine. but i want to set the json object directly into UserEntity bean.

```
public void setUserEntity(String userEntity){
   ...
}
```

any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: You did not specify the url in proxy of store. If you specify it, it will work...

Comment: Thanks Hariharan for your answer. actually i did this by extjs api. api{ update: saveOrUpdateUserAction} specify the url

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS and Struts are different processes running on different machines.

Does the browser send the correct info to the correct URL on the server? You can check this using Chrome Developer Tools.

Can the server accept the correct info on the correct URL independent of ExtJS?

Comment: this is my posted json that firebug show to me:                 {"userEntity":{"id":13,"firstName":"Emad","lastName":"Bayat","nationalCode":"123","username":"emad","age":"25"}}                                              and the server can not accept this data. actually the setter (with UserEntity as argument) does not call. But if i change the setter to get Data as String it works fine. but i do not know why the setter with UserBean as the argument does not work.